# How to upload local system files in my Linux server to Amazon S3 Bucket using ssh?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh

I am trying to upload a file which I have on my Linux server onto my AWS S3 bucket. Can anyone please advise on how to do so as I only find documentations which is related to upload the files to EC2 instead.

I do have the .pem certificate present on my server directory.

I tried to run the following command but it doesn't solve the issue

```
scp -i My_PEM_FILE.pem "MY_FILE_TO_BE_UPLOADED.txt" MY_USER@S3-INSTANCE.IP.ADDRESS.0.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to upload to Amazon S3 by using SSH.

The easiest way to upload from anywhere to an Amazon S3 bucket is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp MY_FILE_TO_BE_UPLOADED.txt s3://my-bucket/
```

This will require an Access Key and a Secret Key to be stored via the `aws configure` command. You can obtain these keys from your IAM User in the IAM management console (Security Credentials tab).

See: [aws s3 cp — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @John. If that is the case, does it mean that I need to be connected to my instance first before being able to use the aws command? I tried to run the command which you have attached above but it says that the command is not found

Comment: The AWS CLI needs to be installed on the system you want to run it from. So, if you want to run it from a Linux server, it needs to be installed on that server. It comes installed by default on Amazon Linux AMIs. Otherwise, follow the [link](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for installation information.